# How to check two conditions for one variable?

Tags: python, if-statement

Very basic issue that I do not understand:
My variable `step` has be 1 or 5 and I want to check it with if statement, and raise an error if the condition is not verified.

```
step = input("Choose a step, in nm, for the wavelength (1 or 5):")
if (
        (step != 1) or (step != 5)
):
    raise ValueError
```

But if I declare 1 or 5 for `step` I end with a `ValueError`.

I tried to do the thing in reverse, checking if `step` is equal to 1 or 5 but without success. And also with the `if ... not in` but no success to.

I am sure this is a very basic little thing but I don't see it.

Thanks for help

Comment: Your condition will always be true. Do you perhaps meant to use `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: @Gulzar yes it's `str` type, should I have `float ` instead ?

Comment: @kuro I tried with and also but it fails

Comment: if input is 1, `step!=1` is false, and `step!=5` is true => false || true is true. And vice versa.

Comment: @гиви, you also need to convert the `step` to integer before checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `or` condition in your `if` statement

As you say if any one of the conditions is false i.e,

```
if (
        (step != 1) or (step != 5)
):
```

As one of the condition will always satisfy and will raise value error.

What i mean is; If your input is 1, the the other part (step !== 5) is be true and will return valueError and same will happen with 5 as an input.

So the solution will be;

```
step = int(input("Choose a step, in nm, for the wavelength (1 or 5):"))
if (
        (step != 1) and (step != 5)
):
    raise ValueError
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your code:

you have to convert input from string to int, and you mixed `or` with `and`

```
step_str = input("Choose a step, in nm, for the wavelength (1 or 5):")
step = int(step_str)
if (
        (step != 1) and (step != 5)
):
    raise ValueError
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Problems

- `type comparison`: `input` returns a `str`, and you used `int` in the `if` test
- `boolean testing`, with an `OR` it'll always fail, it'll always be different of one of them, use `and`

#### Fix

```
step = int(input("Choose a step, in nm, for the wavelength (1 or 5):"))
if step != 1 and step != 5:
    raise ValueError
```

#### Better

With an inclusion test

```
step = int(input("Choose a step, in nm, for the wavelength (1 or 5):"))
if step not in (1, 5):
    raise ValueError
```